# Tensor product of a ring with itself

Tags: ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative ring then $R \otimes_{R} R \cong R$. Is this still true if $R$ is non-commutative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some left $R$-module $M$, we have $R \otimes_R M \cong M$ as abelian groups (or in fact left $R$-modules):

We have the linear map $M \to R \otimes_R M,\, m \mapsto 1 \otimes m$. By the universal property of the tensor product there is a linear map $R \otimes_R M \to M$ mapping $r \otimes m$ to $rm$. One checks that they are inverse to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you are writing an isomorphism $r_1\otimes_R r_2\mapsto r_1\cdot_R r_2$ on $R-R$-bimodules using the composition $\cdot_R$ in $R$. 
The bimodule structure on $R\otimes_R R$ is given by the left and right actions  $r'\cdot_l (r_1\otimes_R r_2):=r'\cdot_R r_1\otimes r_2$ and $(r_1\otimes_R r_2)\cdot_r r^*:=r_1\otimes_R r_2\cdot_R r^*$; the bimodule structure on $R$ uses the associativity of $\cdot_R $. The inverse is constructed using the unit $1_R$ in $R$.